# How do I persist query string throughout a user session without using a cookie?

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a better way using javascript to persist url query string throughout user session in client side other than using cookie?

url:

```
 http://site.com/?q=query
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I would like to modify some content on pages based on the query, the problem is the landing page has the query string. but going to sequential pages will lose the query string. I can't touch the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do that in HTML4.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.name` property. It'll store any string you need. And then check the property value on other pages.

Works on older browsers too.